# PySerial - readline stops or repeats

Tags: python, pyserial

I wrote simple code to read data from sensor it works but it always stops or repeats the last value.

```
import serial
import codecs
import time

com = serial.Serial(port='COM5', baudrate =115200,bytesize=8,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,rtscts =True, timeout=0.1) 


while True:
    if com.in_waiting:
        data = com.readline()
        print(data.decode())
        time.sleep(2)
```

Output:

```
+UUDF:6C1DEBA413DF,-30,-90,50,0,39,"6C1DEBA0999A","",4125
+UUDF:6C1DEBA413DF,-30,-90,50,0,39,"6C1DEBA0999A","",4128
```

Works <80 times or repeats last row.

I would like to get an infinite loop reading.

**Update:**

From logs:

```
INFO:root:b'+UUDF:6C1DEBA413DF,-34,90,-90,0,39,"6C1DEBA0999A","",4374\r\n'
INFO:root:b'\r\n'
INFO:root:b'+UUDF:6C1DEBA413DF,-42,90,-90,0,37,"6C1DEBA0999A","",4402\r\n'
```

So script stopped when missing that: **b'\r\n'** beetween received information.

Comment: How do you know that's now what the sensor is sending?

Comment: My code works but less then around 70-80 times, more than 80 times it is stop or repeats last value.